# Remove last slash from URL with regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to remove last slash from a URL:

```
(.*)\/
```

i.e.: http://www.domain.com/clients/

If applied the regex to the example, it does the work fine, but the problem is when the URL does not have the last slash (it occur from time to time). It removes **/clients**.

How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: wouldn't `\/$` work?  What flavor of regex?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regex to remove only last slash in the URL

```
\/$
```

explanation:

```
\/ matches the character / literally
$ assert position at end of a line
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fB5tK2/2)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone will wonder: you can use
`(.*[^\\\/]{1,})([\\\/]{1,}$)`
to match any number of trailing slashes, both `/` and `\`. This may not be very useful for URIs, but may be useful for paths, in case your code needs to check/remove trailing slashes both on Windows and *NIX.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
(.*)\/$
```

This means that / is at the end of the input.
Hope it helps